# Is GOCE designed to break up in the atmosphere?

Tags: artificial-satellite, reentry, construction, goce

Soon, ESA is planning to deorbit GOCE, letting it burn up in the atmosphere. It seems this has been the plan for a long time - so why won't the satellite be completely annihilated into pieces small enough to not pose any threat at all?

Was breaking up in the atmosphere a design criteria for GOCE?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but de-orbiting satellites and letting them burn up over a large uninhabited area (I can't think of any spacecraft that weren't de-orbited into the Pacific Ocean) is a very standard procedure for all types of satellites and even space station. All of the Russian progress cargo ships that resupply the space station do this, and have been doing this since the late 1970's.

Breaking up in the atmosphere is rarely (almost never) a design criteria because the heat generated by flying through the atmosphere at near-orbital speeds is higher than the melting point of any metal. Some pieces can still survive if they're buried deep enough into the satellite and the heat doesn't have time to conduct through the entire spacecraft, which is why they are de-orbited over uninhabited land masses.

In addition to the heating, atmospheric drag helps to break apart a spacecraft. Think about sticking your hand out a car window going ~60 mph. If you face your palm towards the airflow you feel a much stronger force than if your hand is parallel to the airflow. Now image that kind of force at ~17000 mph.

GOCE was more aerodynamic than other spacecraft because of its mission requirements, but it still burned up when it re-entered just a few weeks ago. However, they didn't plan things out quite carefully enough and they ran out of propellant before re-entry, and so they did not have the ability to target the re-entry into the Pacific. Luckily, the spacecraft disintegrated mostly in the Atlantic over the Falkland Islands.

Comment: Actually, we don't know if GOCE burnt up completely. We have some photos of it breaking up on reentry west of Falklands, but some pieces did look like they could have splashed into Atlantic. Sats are designed to be thermoconductive to increase convective heat transfer surface since they face huge temp delta Sun to shadow facing side. Breaking up due to enormous pressure will also help increase the friction area, but rare few parts would actually melt. Burn they might, but larger pieces would only get really hot on the exposed side, and lose much of that heat through ablation of its materials.